# Magento2.2.2 : Custom Category Attribute value Not Saving?

Tags: module, attributes, magento2.2, custom-attributes

I've create a module to add a custom attribute to my categories,the field shows on my category pages but it doesn't save the values?

Working on **`Magento ver. 2.2.2`**

Can anyone advise why this isn't working.

> /app/code/NameSpace/CategoryAttributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php 

// File: Namespace/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'ss_category_color', [
            'type'          => 'varchar',
            'label'         => 'Category Color',
            'input'         => 'text',
            'source'        => '',
            'visible'       => true,
            'default'       => '',
            'required'      => false,
            'user_defined'  => false,
            'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'         => 'General Information',
        ]);
    }
}
```

> /app/code/NameSpace/CategoryAttributes/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml -->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general_information">
        <field name="ss_category_color">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Color</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> app/code/Ravindra/Categoryattributes/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="ss_category_color">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Category Color</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> app/code/Ravindra/Categoryattributes/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php


namespace Ravindra\Categoryattributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "2.2.2", "<")) {
        //Your upgrade script
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> app/code/Ravindra/Categoryattributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
    <?php


namespace Ravindra\Categoryattributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        //Your install script

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'ss_category_color',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Category Color',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Ravindra/Categoryattributes/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php


namespace Ravindra\Categoryattributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> app/code/Ravindra/Categoryattributes/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php


namespace Ravindra\Categoryattributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "2.2.2", "<")) {
        //Your upgrade script
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Now check screen short

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer, just i need to edit the install function right? or i need to create an upgrade script?

Comment: I've create a new module and it's working perfectly but i want to update nad fix the problem in my existing module how i can do that please?

Comment: now check my updated code.

Comment: most welcome @mahmoudismail

Comment: please my answer upvote  @mahmoudismail

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala: that attribute not save value according to specific store, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 
            'ss_category_color', 
            [
                'type'          => 'varchar',
                'label'         => 'Category Color',
                'input'         => 'text',
                'visible'       => true,
                'required'      => false,
                'user_defined'  => false,
                'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'         => 'General Information'
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but still not working.